# recoding of a huge file

Tags: unix, text

I have a huge file that has the following format:

```
#pair:  0   1   0   1   0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
0   0   1   
#pair:  1   2   0   1   1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
#pair:  1   2   1   2   0   0   1
```

etc etc
What I hope I can do using command in Linux is to find each line that starts with "#pair:" and move the last 3 columns directly bellow this line.For example:

```
#pair:  1   2   1   2   0   0   1
```

changes to:

```
#pair:  1   2   1   2   
0   0   1
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please define `huge`. What have you tried so far? Have you looked into things like `sed` and `awk` for example?

Comment: Happy to be here! My file has 5.769.601 lines. I have tried to search for a solution but unfortunately I am not a very good linux user yet!

Comment: A few dozen megabytes is not "huge" by today's standards.  You should be done in a few seconds.

Comment: ok, I apologize for the poor choise of words! I will give it a go and let you know!

Comment: Please do not post your question to multiple sites at once (e.g. [SU]  and [SO]). This will lead to one of them being deleted eventually. Thank you!

Comment: Yes you are right and I apologise. I did not know the 2 sites are connected and I posted in both looking for an answer. Beginners fault sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough with Awk:

```
awk '/^#pair:/ { $6 = "\n" $6 }1' file >newfile
```

This presumes that the field count is constant, and that whitespace at the end of the `#pair:` line is tolerable.  Both of these assumptions are moderately easy to fix or work around, but at the expense of code readability.  (Use something like `$(NF-2)` instead of `$6` if the field count can change, but you always want the last three.  Add a simple `sub()` to trim whitespace if necessary.)

The regex matches on lines which begin with `#pair:` and the action says to prepend a newline before the sixth field.

The lone `1` is an Awk idiom to print every input line to standard output.

This reads `file` and places the output in `newfile`.